# ENcryption / Decryption using OpenSSL

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

i am working on a protocol for key agreement. Got stuck at a point where i want to encrypt and send a message from server and recieve and decrypt at client. Following is the snippet for server.

`

```
// Generate an initialization vector (IV) for CBC mode
    const EVP_CIPHER* cipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc(); // Use the desired cipher algorithm
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx_encrypt = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    const unsigned char* plaintext = sessionKey;
    size_t plaintext_len = sessionKeyLen;
    const int MAX_TEXT_LENGTH = 256;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    
    // Initialize the encryption/decryption context
    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_encrypt, cipher, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing the cipher context\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt);
    return;
    }

    // Set the session key
    if (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx_encrypt, skeylen) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the key length\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt);
    return;
    }

    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_encrypt, NULL, NULL, skey, NULL, -1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the session key\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt);
    return;
    }
    
    if (RAND_bytes(iv, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error generating IV\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the IV for the encryption operation
    if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx_encrypt, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, skey, iv) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting encryption IV\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Encrypt the plaintext (session key)
    unsigned char ciphertext[MAX_TEXT_LENGTH + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int ciphertext_len;

    if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx_encrypt, ciphertext, &ciphertext_len, plaintext, plaintext_len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting data\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Finalize the encryption
    int final_len;
    if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx_encrypt, ciphertext + ciphertext_len, &final_len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing encryption\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ciphertext_len += final_len;

    const size_t ivLength = EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(EVP_aes_256_cbc()); // Get the length of the IV
    const size_t concatenatedMessageLength = ivLength + ciphertext_len;
    unsigned char concatenatedMessage[concatenatedMessageLength];

    memcpy(concatenatedMessage, iv, ivLength);
    memcpy(concatenatedMessage + ivLength, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    printf("Concatenated Message 1:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < concatenatedMessageLength; i++) {
        printf("%02x", concatenatedMessage[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt);


    // Preparing for Bob's share

    // Generate an initialization vector (IV) for CBC mode
    plaintext = (const unsigned char*)"Verification Message SessionKey";
    plaintext_len = strlen((const char*)plaintext);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx_encrypt2 = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    // Initialize the encryption/decryption context
    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_encrypt2, cipher, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing the cipher context\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt2);
    return;
    }

    // Set the session key
    if (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx_encrypt2, sessionKeyLen) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the key length\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt2);
    return;
    }

    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_encrypt2, NULL, NULL, sessionKey, NULL, -1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the session key\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt2);
    return;
    }


    if (RAND_bytes(iv, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error generating IV\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the IV for the encryption operation
    if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx_encrypt2, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, sessionKey, iv) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting encryption IV\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Encrypt the plaintext (Bob's share)
    if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx_encrypt2, ciphertext, &ciphertext_len, plaintext, plaintext_len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting data\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Finalize the encryption
    if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx_encrypt2, ciphertext + ciphertext_len, &final_len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing encryption\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ciphertext_len += final_len;
    const size_t concatenatedMessageLength2 = ivLength + ciphertext_len;
    unsigned char concatenatedMessage2[concatenatedMessageLength2];

    memcpy(concatenatedMessage2, iv, ivLength);
    memcpy(concatenatedMessage2 + ivLength, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    printf("Concatenated Message 2:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < concatenatedMessageLength2; i++) {
        printf("%02x", concatenatedMessage2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_encrypt2);

    // Sending Server Share and Verification Message
    if (concatenatedMessageLength > 0) {
        send(client_sock_Bob, concatenatedMessage, concatenatedMessageLength, 0);
        // Send the encrypted hash to the server
        usleep(100);
        if (concatenatedMessageLength2 > 0) {
            send(client_sock_Bob, concatenatedMessage2, concatenatedMessageLength2, 0);
        } else {
            printf("Server Verification message is Null: %s\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Session key is Null : %s\n");
    }`
```

In this code, the first message to be encrypted is a sesionkey, encrypted by a key 'skey' (an array). The next message is encrypted by sessionkey. On client side, the client has only skey (an array), it will first decrypt and get the session key and then decrypt next message using that session key. Following is the code

```
`const EVP_CIPHER* cipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc(); // Use the desired cipher algorithm
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx_decrypt = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    char decryptedText1[1024] = {0};
    char decryptedText2[1024] = {0};
    int decryptedText1_len = 0;
    int decryptedText2_len = 0;
    memset(decryptedText1, 0, sizeof(decryptedText1));

    // Initialize the encryption/decryption context
    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_decrypt, cipher, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing the cipher context\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt);
    return;
    }

    // Set the session key
    if (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx_decrypt, skeylen) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the key length\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt);
    return;
    }

    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_decrypt, NULL, NULL, skey, NULL, -1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the session key\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt);
    return;
    }
    
    // Extract the IV from the concatenated message 2
    memcpy(iv, concatenatedMessage2, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);

    // Set the IV for the decryption operation
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx_decrypt, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, skey, iv) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting decryption IV\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    // Decrypt the ciphertext
    if (EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx_decrypt, decryptedText1, &decryptedText1_len, concatenatedMessage2 + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH, concatenatedMessageLength2 - EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting data\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    // Finalize the decryption
    int final_len;
    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx_decrypt, decryptedText1 + decryptedText1_len, &final_len) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing decryption\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    decryptedText1_len += final_len;
    
    // Print the decrypted plaintext
    printf("Decrypted Text: %.*s\n", decryptedText1_len, decryptedText1);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt);



    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx_decrypt2 = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    // Initialize the encryption/decryption context
    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_decrypt2, cipher, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing the cipher context\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt2);
    return;
    }

    // Set the session key
    if (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(ctx_decrypt2, decryptedText1_len) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the key length\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt2);
    return;
    }

    if (EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx_decrypt2, NULL, NULL, decryptedText1, NULL, -1) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the session key\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx_decrypt2);
    return;
    }
    // Extract the IV from the concatenated message 1
    memcpy(iv, concatenatedMessage1, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);

    // Set the IV for the decryption operation
    if (EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx_decrypt2, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, decryptedText1, iv) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting decryption IV\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    // Decrypt the ciphertext
    if (EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx_decrypt2, decryptedText2, &decryptedText2_len, concatenatedMessage1 + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH, concatenatedMessageLength1 - EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting data\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    // Finalize the decryption
    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx_decrypt2, decryptedText2 + decryptedText2_len, &final_len) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finalizing decryption\n");
    exit(1);
    }
    decryptedText2_len += final_len;

    // Print the decrypted plaintext
    printf("Decrypted Text: %.*s\n", decryptedText2_len, decryptedText2);
```

The problem i am facing is in decrypting. it gets stuck at decrypting first message giving "error decrypting data" as output. I have verified skey and iv at both ends already. I would be thankful for the help

Comment: Not much of a protocol. The techniques for key agreement without key exchange were worked out decades ago. Why aren't you using one of them? RSA, DH, ...

Comment: It is a snippet from a protocol, not the protocol. In my protocol, the key is established as skey. This is done with multiple clients and then the session key is calculated. Now, this snippet is to send that session key and verify it at the other end as well

Comment: Exactly so: it is the snippet that transmits the session key. In the protocols I mentioned the session key is ever transmitted at all: it is computed independently at both ends. A session key that is never transmitted is inherently far more secure than one that is. SSL works this way, for example.

Comment: You are right but that is amongst only server and client. In this we have multiple clients and the concept of group key agreement is being implemented. The established secret is skey which is not being transmitted. Kindly tell me if you can help with the error in code

Comment: @user207421: RSA is key _transport_ or _wrap_ but not agreement. 'key exchange' is sometimes used, particularly in SSL/TLS, to cover both agreement _and_ transport. This Q is (apparently) a different (symmetric) kind of key wrap. OP: I believe your problem is that concatenatedMessage[1] is the one that contains sessionkey-under-skey (which can and should be decrypted by skey) NOT concatenatedMessage2.  Also as coding advice, when a libcrypto routine like EVP_* returns an error, for more info you should look at OpenSSL's error queue, most easily with `ERR_print_errors[_fp]`. ...

Comment: ... Also FYI wrapping a symmetric key, which should be (all or nearly all) random bits, is one of the few places we don't need an IV for semantic security or even CBC, and ECB is acceptable and has been traditional, but a mode _designed_ for keywrap (with little or no expansion) like SP800-38F or RFC3394 is even better. But that's design and crypto, not programming, so offtopic.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my problem. Yes, concatenated message 1 must be decrypted using skey and is not being done. Can you tell me why?

Comment: i can go with ECB, however as you must have realized after watching the code, i am a newbie. :) . can you help me identify the reason for not decrypting?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments pointed out, you have:

```
...
    // Extract the IV from the concatenated message 2
    memcpy(iv, concatenatedMessage2, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
...
    // Extract the IV from the concatenated message 1
    memcpy(iv, concatenatedMessage1, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
...
```

When it should be:

```
...
    // Extract the IV from the concatenated message 1
    memcpy(iv, concatenatedMessage1, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
...
    // Extract the IV from the concatenated message 2
    memcpy(iv, concatenatedMessage2, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
...
```

i.e. Your using concatenatedMessage2 iv to decrypt concatenatedMessage1 and concatenatedMessage1 iv to decrypt concatenatedMessage2.

Comment: You are right but logically that is correct as the first thing i am sending from server side is encrypted by skey and on client side it is being decrypted by skey too. However, i have corrected it. Still it does not decrypt